# Update second chart on mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to replicate the [trulia's graph](http://www.trulia.com/vis/tru247/) with [D3.js](https://github.com/mbostock/d3), but only the main chart (the heatmap) and the daily graph (the graph bar that changes when you hover the mouse over a specific point on the main chart).

Using [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084), I've managed to build the main chart with my own data. I also have the second chart. But now I have no clue on how to update this second chart when I hover on a point on main chart.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `d3.dispatch`, an example can be found at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5872848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, what you're going to have is two different charts with different data. The first chart (the heatmap) controls the other one. Each data point on the heatmap has a `day` and an `hour` attribute, which we want to use to control the second graph. To do this, we can use two functions to control the second graph, and then call both of them every time someone clicks on a point.

The first function just needs to build a blank graph for the target day.

```
function updateGraphDay(newDay){
    //Remove current graph and build graph for newDay
}
```

The second is one that will highlight a certain hour on the bar chart. I'm assuming here that your bar chart is in its own SVG, `barGraphSVG`, and all of the bars have the class `hourBar`, and that the data you used to create it has an `hour` attribute, like the heat map data.

```
function updateGraphHour(newHour){
    barGraphSVG.selectAll('.hourBar')
        .classed('selectedBar', function(d){ return d.hour === newHour });
}
```

Now you just call both of these when you hover on one of the `rect` elements in the bar chart.

```
heatMap.on('hover', function(d){
    updateGraphDay(d.day);
    updateGraphHour(d.hour);
});
```

Comment: Indeed. Or just add the selection to the original function (less modular approach).